# Set resolution of file when splitting files with GD

Tags: php, gd, php-5.6

How can i add the resoulution of the output files as 300 PPI.
The resoulution of the input file is 300 PPI . The two output files 96 PPI, but should be 300 PPI aswell.
I cant get the function imageresolution to work in the code below.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageresolution.php

```
$file1= dirname($filename) . "/000-frontpage.jpg";
$file2= dirname($filename) . "/000-back.jpg";
$orgfile= $filename;
 
$info = getimagesize($orgfile);
$width=$info[0];
$height=$info[1];


$orig = imagecreatefromjpeg($orgfile);
$leftSide = imagecreatetruecolor($width/2, $height);
$rightSide = imagecreatetruecolor($width/2, $height);
imagecopy($leftSide, $orig, 0, 0, $width/2, 0, $width/2, $height);
imagecopy($rightSide, $orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width/2, $height);
e
imagejpeg($leftSide, $file2);
imagejpeg($rightSide, $file1)
```

Comment: Please don’t tell us that you could not get something to work, without showing us what you actually tried.

Comment: Seems like the function imageresolution that i have tryed to use is PHP 7 > - Im using php 5.6. ( is not an option to upgrade the php version)

Comment: You are not seriously still messing around with a PHP 5 version? The last 5 branch has not even received security fixed for a long time now! https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php